# Updating Cassandra Map Value through querybuilder

Tags: collections, cassandra-2.0

Cassandra support updating specific value in Collection by syntax

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD todo map<timestamp, text>

UPDATE users SET todo['2012-10-2 12:00'] = 'throw my precious into mount doom'
  WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_map_t.html

Did not see any example of using QueryBuilder to update specific row in Map. How it can be done?

Comment: 1.  This appears to be a Cassandra question, not a Spring Data Cassandra question.

Comment: 2.  This doesn't appear to be a question at all.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have several options.

**1/ Build your own query based on the CQL one.**

Example: Consider that you have a table named Interactions and in your schema  a column of type  named 'attributes'.

```
String update ="UPDATE demo.Interactions SET attributes=attributes + {'i':'j'} where id='ff';   
SimpleStatement statement = new SimpleStatement(update);
session.execute(statement);
```

**2/ Use Java API.**

Java API is not that documented indeed.
Let's take an example

a- Create an update object using queryBuilder

```
Update update = QueryBuilder.update(keyspace, tableName);
```

b- Then populate with 'put' or 'putAll' functions. put/putAll will add/update content

```
  update.with(QueryBuilder.putAll(key, map));
```

To remove a key, set the content of a key to null, like:

```
for (Object item : map.keySet()) {                    
  update.with(
    QueryBuilder.put(columName, item, null)
  );
}
```

Then execute the query.

Following methods are available for different types:
LIST:

```
QueryBuilder.appendAll(...)
QueryBuilder.discardAll(...)
```

SET:

```
QueryBuilder.addAll(...)
QueryBuilder.removeAll(...)
```

MAP:

```
QueryBuilder.putAll(...)
QueryBuilder.put(...)
```

The list is not exhautive. 
Have a look in QueryBuilder class if you do not find what you are looking for.

Best regards and best luck with Cassandra.